# Serve non static laravel files with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, reverse-proxy, non-static

I have a laravel app on docker. The app can store and manage files that the user provides once in a while. i have configured a route to serve this files with laravel, but nginx is not loading them.

do i have a missing configuration ?

[image]
already try different locations blocks approaches but no luck so far.

````
server {

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/vma/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass vma_php_server:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

}```
````

Comment: Are you sure this is an nginx problem? If other routes in your app are working, and other images are being served without issue then it would suggest maybe a problem with the application. Is it possible the controller method the route points to  is returning a 404?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, other routes works fine. but the routes for loading files are failing. i have two folders within the public folder for handling some images and pdf files. those ones are not being loaded.

Comment: If your convinced it's a nginx issue, I would suggest moving the question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as you may get a better response there. You might need to look into adding another `location` block to support the image extensions your serving and route them to php.

Comment: @Jeemusu thank you very much for that recommendation!